# C# WPF datagrid template column with combobox having different datasource

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

[image]I have a window with 2 controls. One is a combobox `(cmbUnit)` and another is a DataGrid `(dgvProducts)`

`cmbUnits` is binded with **`List<Unit>`** collection & the `Unit` class is below

```
public class Unit
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*Note : Display member is Name & Value member is ID*

Where as, `dgvProducts` is binded with **`List<Product>`** Collection & the `Product` class is below

```
public class Product
{
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string ProductName { get; set; }
       public int UnitID { get; set; }
}
```

Here, i am selecting `UnitID` from my db table `(TBL_PRODUCTS)`, I can  also retrieve `UnitName` by joining table. for now, i want to keep only `UnitID` in my `Product` class.

My question is, My datagrid has a column `(datagridTemplateColumn)` with a combobox as the child, and i want to show the `UnitName` inside it by passing `UnitID` same like my combobox control `(cmbUnit)`

My Datas inside datagrid should be

```
--------------------------------------------------
ID      UnitName     ProductName
--------------------------------------------------
12345    Kg         Sample Product
```

Where **`Kg`** should be displayed inside a combobox.
How to achieve this ? Help me !

My XAML code for `cmbUnit` is

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="1" Name="cmbUnit" ></ComboBox>
```

where i bind datas to this control from code behind.

XAML for `dgvProducts`

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              Name="dgvProduct"  
              Grid.Row="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID" Width="50" CanUserSort="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding ID}"></Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Unit" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox IsEnabled="False"
                            Name="cmbGrUnit"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Units}"
                            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                            SelectedValuePath="ID"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding UnitID}"
                            ></ComboBox>
                        <!--<Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Product Name" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding ProductName}"></Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn></DataGrid.Columns>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add xaml code of your combobox?

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk Hi, question is modified, XAML codes are added, please have a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="1" Name="cmbUnit" ></ComboBox>
```

With ItemsSource set from code behind

```
cmbUnit.ItemsSource = this.Units
```

then you can use this cmbUnit as a source object for your binding in the following way:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Unit" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, ElementName=cmbUnit}"
                    SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=UnitID}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Note, that ComboBox inside DataGrid have its own DataContext, which contains an element of your DataGrid's ItemsSource. Also, it is part of DataTemplate, which means it is not an object itself, so you cannot bind directly to it from code behind.

Comment: your solution is not working, It simply adds a combobox without values. Also  `{Binding Path=DataContext.Units, ElementName=window}` here  ElementName is just window or my window name (ex : winProducts ) ? suppose if i use a usercontrol instead of window what value should i use for ElementName ? Because i changed it to a usercontrol ?

Comment: I see naming confuses you, I've changed the name. Please, read about [binding by ElementName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.elementname?view=winrt-18362).

Comment: Still its an empty combobox, I have changed ElementName also, Instead of taking DataContext.Units (Where this is the itemSource of cmbUnit, i already mentioned i have two controls. one is combobox & another is datagrid ) can i use ElementName as cmbUnit ? if so what is the value for Path ?

Comment: Can you, please, add in your question how you set DataContext of your cmbUnit?

Comment: global variable : `public List<Unit> Units { get; set; }`
inside a method:

  `this.Units = _UnitLogic.GetUnits();
                this.cmbUnit.ItemsSource = this.Units;
                this.cmbUnit.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
                this.cmbUnit.SelectedValuePath = "ID";`    I have updated question with a wareframe, please have a look if you have any doubts

Comment: `<DataTemplate>
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Units, ElementName=ucProductRate}"
                                      SelectedValuePath="ID" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=UnitID}" />
                            
                           
</DataTemplate>` This is for combobox column

Comment: Well, than you should use ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, ElementName=cmbUnit}"

Comment: Perfect ! This is the solution i am looking for!

Comment: Please update your answer, it seems DataContext.Unit instead of ItemSource of cmbUnit